# Count Employee's Departmentwise

Tags: inner-join, self-join

I have two table employee and Native leave I want count employee’s Department wise and count employee in native

**Employee Table:-**

```
Empno Name Depart Addre Age Exisisting_No
-----------------------------------------

1   Abc Acc Kkk 20  1

2   Efg Hr  Hhh 22  2

3   ijk Acc Yyy 21  3

4   Mno Hr  Zzz 20  4
```

**Native Leave Table:-**

```
Exisisting_No Name From To Reason
---------------------------------

2   Efg 30/01/14    04/02/14    personal
```

**Want Output Like:-**

```
Depart EmpNo NL
---------------

Hr  2   1
Acc 2   0
```

So please any one can help me and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.Dept
       , count(Empno)
       , count(NL.Exisisting_No) 
FROM   Employee e LEFT JOIN NativeLeave NL ON e.Exisisting_No = NL.Exisisting_No
GROUP BY e.Dept
```